# How can I set focus to a split form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am simply attempting to switch focus to a split form using a button located on another form.  This can be broken down to code a simple as this.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Forms.Form1.SetFocus

End Sub
```

This code will work so long as Form1 is in open "Single Form" view.  The moment that you change Form1 to "Split Form" view, it no longer changes to Form1 and no error messages pop up.

How can I accomplish setting focus to a split form since obviously the normal way doesn't appear to work.

Edit:  I would like to avoid the docmd.Runcommand OpenForm solution or the toggling visible false then true method of solving this problem.

Comment: just use docmd.openform frm_name,acNormal will open the form, if already opened will bring in front (modal forms still stay on top)

Comment: I had thought about that, though that causes all On load and all On current events to fire again.  The form itself is fairly resource intensive so it feels like that is a fairly clunky solution for something that should be super simple.

Comment: In case anyone reads my comment, it is not accurate, those events do not run.  Just thought I would mention that and the solution provide by krish works.

Comment: @krish I am doing a past post cleanup, can you post your comment as an answer so I am able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use docmd.openform frm_name,acNormal will open the form, if already opened will bring it to front (modal forms still stay on top)